# How to move and align?

Tags: gimp, alignment

Can anyone explain how to move the star, so it is 64 pixels above the text and howto align the star horizontally with the text?

When I use the Fuzzy Select tool on the black pixels, it only selects the outline of the star.

I use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) instead of Photoshop, if that makes a difference.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Fuzzy Select](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-fuzzy-select.html) tool only selects areas of similar colors.  To select the entire star, after clicking the black outline hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click the yellow interior and each of the eyes.

Or, perhaps easier, first use [Rectangle Select](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-rect-select.html) to select a rectangle around the star, then switch to Fuzzy Select and subtract the white area around the star from the selection by clicking it while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Once you have the star selected, I'd suggest moving it to a separate layer so you won't have to repeat the process the next time you want to move it.  Perhaps the easiest way to do that is to cut the star out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, paste it back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and click the [New Layer](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#gimp-layer-dialog-new) icon in the [Layers window](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#gimp-layer-dialog) to turn the resulting "floating selection" into a new layer.  (Or you can use the [Select→Float](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-float.html) menu command (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) to float the selection without cutting and pasting, then turn it into a new layer as above.)

Do the same for the text, and then use the [Align Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html) to align the two layers as Jack suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would say select the star and move :D okay jokes apart..

Please see - [Gimp Align Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html)

[image: Align tool]

[image]

Align  `relative to First item` will do the job

---

- [Gimp Move Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-move.html)

[image]

---

> When I use the Fuzzy Select tool on the black pixels, it only selects
>   the outline of the star.

Because The Fuzzy Select (Magic Wand) tool is designed to select areas of the current layer or image based on color similarity. so its not right tool for this [Read More](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-fuzzy-select.html)

I would suggest you to read the [the gimp tools manual](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tools.html) 
its worth reading if you are working frequently....

Hope this will help a bit.